# How to override collect() in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to override collect() using after Plugin in magento2.
I need to set custom description in totals.

> Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount as Source;

class Discount
{

    public function afterCollect(Source $subject, $result, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment $shippingAssignment, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $subject;
        }
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        $total->setDiscountDescription(implode(",", $address->getFullDescription()));
        return $subject;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the code which you have tried so far, so someone can find what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of return `$subject` return `$result`

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount as Source;

class Discount
{

    public function afterCollect(Source $subject, $result, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment $shippingAssignment, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $subject;
        }
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        $total->setDiscountDescription(implode(",", $address->getFullDescription()));
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `after` plugin, you should use `around` plugin to fulfill your requirements. `around` plugin will allow to manipulate your parameters as well as the result of the function.

The other thing you are doing wrong is the return parameter. `after` plugin should return `$result` instead of `$subject`
Try like.

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount as Source;

class Discount
{
    public function aroundCollect(Source $subject, 
        \Closure $proceed, 
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, 
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment $shippingAssignment, 
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        $result = $proceed($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $result;
        }
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        $total->setDiscountDescription(implode(",", $address->getFullDescription()));
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why we go for around Plugin?

Comment: Here you need to update your parameter variables. `after` plugin will only allow you to manipulate the result of the function, while `around` will allow to change the input parameters as well as the output results.

Comment: Ok .... ........

Comment: I have used around plugin ,It will throw the error  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Quote\\Discount::collect(),

Comment: @ManoM I have updated the answer. Please try to use updated code. In my previous answer there were arguments missing in `proceed` function.

Comment: Ok .... ........

Comment: If u know that, can u guide me?..............https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235518/how-to-override-template-in-magento-2