# How to override template in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to remove the line below

```
<span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponLabel()"></span>
```

in `Magento_SalesRule/cart/totals/discount.html`

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {                
            'Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount': {
                'XXX_YYY/js/view/cart/totals/discount': true

            },
        }}};

define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function (Component, quote) {
    'use strict';alert("cart");

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'XXX_YYY/cart/totals/discount'
            }});
    }
});
```

And remove the line in this template, But I can not get the template in UI

Comment: You added your `mixins` code in **requirejs-config.js** file, right?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: why not remove label from admin cart rule.

Comment: I need this for discount calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override your discount.html file

> open & copy file
>   `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

Then put file here

> app/design/frontend/Magento_SalesRule/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

Remove condition in discount.html file

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() --> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

Your discount.html file code look like.

```
 <!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<tr class="totals">
    <th colspan="1" style="" class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: title"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount" data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}">
        <span><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Note** : Please check discount file is not override any where